# Collision between Character and Wall

Tags: java, collision-detection

I am trying to write a function inside a `Character` class such that when it collides with the top of a `Wall` object (its a platformer) it returns `true`. So far I have this inside the `Character` class:

```
private boolean isTouchingTopOfWall() {
    for (Wall wall: game.getPanel().getWalls())
        if (getBounds().intersects(wall.getBounds()))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

With two functions in the `Character` and `Wall` class like this:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, game.getBlockSize(), game.getBlockSize());
}
```

This works perfectly apart from that when the `Character` object collides with the side of the `Wall` object, it also returns `true`, when I want it so that it only returns `true` when it collides from the top. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you always know where the top of the wall will be, you could just add a check to make sure its that part

```
 if (getBounds().intersects(wall.getBounds()) && 
    wall.intersectPoint == *wall.getTopBounds*) //you'd probably have to write this
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isTouchingTopOfWall() {
    for (Wall wall: game.getPanel().getWalls())
        if (getBounds().intersects(wall.getBounds())) {
            int charBottomY = character.getY() + character.getBlockSize();
            int wallTopY = wall.getY();
            if(charBottomY <= wallTopY)
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Once you've determined you intersect, insert some code that determines if you're above the wall or not. If you're not above the wall, skip to the next wall.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isTouchingTopOfWall() {
    for (Wall wall: game.getPanel().getWalls())
        if (getBounds().y< wall.getBounds().y)  //top wall
            return true;
        if (getBounds().y + getBounds().getHeight() > wall.getBounds().getHeight())
            return true;   //bottom wall
    return false;
}
```

Should only check for bottom and top wall (which you can ommit), more elegant ways of doing this but at least you won't have to change `getWalls()`